# jQuery autocomplete list position change

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I would like to move position a bit to the left of my jQuery UI suggestion list. Here function and everything work very fine

Unfortunately I have no idea how to move that list a bit to left align left about 10px the page is responsive that is why scared that how to move left.

I think this is the documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add  `margin-left: -11px;` in to the list DIV

Answer (score 1):

You can set the style in this class

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-hover, .ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-active
{
    margin-left: -10px !important;
}
```

Try adding this in your CSS and not in the jQuery-ui CSS file